# Trying to get historical data for multiple securities using python and IB API - df not clearing between loops

Tags: python, pandas, interactive-brokers, tws, ib-api

I'm trying to get historical data for several products through the IB API, and store each product in a dataframe (which I need to save in separate csv files).

This is my code, the main issue is that the dataframe isn't clearing between loops, when moving onto the second loop the df contains data for 2 products, the third for 3.  I'm not sure where / how to clear the df.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = []

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume])
           
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        print("HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId:", reqId, "from", start, "to", end)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)

def run_loop():
    app.run()
    
app = IBapi()

#Create contract object
ES_contract = Contract()
ES_contract.symbol = 'ES'
ES_contract.secType = 'FUT'
ES_contract.exchange = 'GLOBEX'
ES_contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth  = '202209'

#Create contract object
VIX_contract = Contract()
VIX_contract.symbol = 'VIX'
VIX_contract.secType = 'IND'
VIX_contract.exchange = 'CBOE'
VIX_contract.currency = 'USD'

#Create contract object
DAX_contract = Contract()
DAX_contract.symbol = 'DAX'
DAX_contract.secType = 'FUT'
DAX_contract.exchange = 'EUREX'
DAX_contract.currency = 'EUR'
DAX_contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth  = '202209'
DAX_contract.multiplier = '25'

products={'ES': ES_contract, 'VIX': VIX_contract,  'DAX': DAX_contract}

nid=1

app.connect('127.0.0.1', 4001, 123)
#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()
time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

def fetchdata_function(name,nid):
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    #Request historical candles
    app.reqHistoricalData(nid, products[name], '', '1 W', '5 mins', 'TRADES', 0, 2, False, [])
    time.sleep(10) #sleep to allow enough time for data to be returned
    df = pd.DataFrame(app.data, columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],unit='s')
    df=df.set_index('Date')
    df.to_csv('1week'+str(name)+'5min.csv')  
    print(df)

names=['ES', 'DAX', 'VIX']

for name in names:     
    fetchdata_function(name,nid)
    nid=nid+1   
    
app.disconnect()
```

Comment: You are persisting the app object throughout your code. You'd need need some sort of clean up method that clears your dataframe (that you then call at the end of your  fetchdata function).

Comment: after `df.to_csv` just do `df=df[0:0] ` to clear everything.  I haven't tested with your code.

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary and append the app.data as a key value pair in the historicaldata callback. Then you can access them separately - in fact converting a dict to multi-level dataframe is also possible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).